# What is the energy of a Gaussian wave packet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

Suppose we have a potential barrier situation, that is $V(x)$ is zero everywhere except on the interval $[-a,a]$, where it is equal to some $V_0 > 0$. Introduce some Gaussian shaped wave packet to the left of the barrier, moving right.

What is the energy of the packet (i.e. of the system described by this wavefunction) at each instant of time?

Well, the wavefunction $\psi(x,t)$ is not an energy eigenstate, so the question is asking about the expected value of the energy, I suppose. Does that just mean carrying out the calculation

$$\langle E(t) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \langle \psi_t | x \rangle \langle x | H \psi_t \rangle  \quad ?$$

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: Note that $E(t)$ is constant. The wavefunction is only a Gaussian at $t=0$, after which the shape is not so easy to compute.

Comment: The expected value of kinetic energy should be easy and intuitive. The expected value of $V(x)$ is harder, and will be expressible in terms of the error function.

Comment: The way I imagined this, it is still more or less a gaussian until it collides with the barrier, then some weird stuff happens for a while, and then its two almost-gaussians travelling in opposite direction.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. They are not perfect Gaussians, though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nemis L. pointed out, the expectation value $\langle H\rangle$ is constant, because of Ehrenfest's theorem:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle H \rangle = \frac{1}{i \hbar} \langle [ H,H ] \rangle = 0.$$
The other way of seeing this is that the state can be written as a superposition of orthogonal energy eigenstates.

Obligatory image:
[image: Scattering of a wave packet off of a square potential barrier]

Goldberg, Schey, and Schwartz, [Computer Generated Motion Pictures of One Dimensional Quantum Mechanical Transmission and Reflection Phenomena](http://ergodic.ugr.es/cphys/lecciones/SCHROEDINGER/ajp.pdf)", Am. J. Phys., 35, 177 (1967).)

Comment: But *every* state can be written as a superposition of the orthogonal energy eigenstates (via Fourier transform), right?

Comment: Yes. It is only a reflection of conservation of energy, not something peculiar to Gaussian states.

Comment: I wonder, how could *energy dissipation* be introduced here? Is it the same as *dispersion*, the word I hear all the time in *dispersion relation* ?

Comment: Dispersion refers to different momenta traveling at different speeds, so that the wave-packet spreads out. In order to model energy dissipation, you would have to model the potential barrier as having it's own dynamics, which can absorb energy. An example is the [Caldeira-Leggett model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dissipation#The_Caldeira-Leggett_or_Harmonic_bath_model).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always wondered how energy conservation was broken, mathmetiacially!

Comment: But if I put two detectors on both sides, only one of them observes the electron and after the scattering, the energy is less than the initial value on each side. The situation is worse if one excludes radiation by considering a barrier like a mirror where the amplitude of the wave packet is halved. Isn't it a violation of the conservation of energy?! Since there's no absorption and radiation of EM waves to compensate the energy loss in the case of scattering from a mirror.

Comment: You can ignore the barrier altogether and just talk about the particle after it was detected by a single detector. Because the particle didn't start out in an energy eigenstate, it will seem to "collapse" into a state with different energy. But the failure of conservation of energy is illusory. Such non-energy eigenstates usually come up when we ignore other degrees of freedom and ask "what does the wavefunction look like if I project into this or that subspace of states". E.g. my energy eigenstate particle got detected by a detector and now I'm focusing on its new position eigenstate.